# Content tag in string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

```
t = "Some "
t += content_tag :span, "random ", class: "bold_style"
t += "words."
return t
```

I'm concatenating a string and one of the words need to be bold, so I want to wrap that word with a span tag and class.

How can I tell Rails that it's a span tag and not text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you output string that has html inside use `html_safe`

example:

```
s = "string 1"
s.html_safe # outputs string 1

s2 = "<p> string 2 </p>"
s2.html_safe # will generate p tag with string 2 text inside
```

you could

```
return t.html_safe
```